What is the difference between different types of Discrete Cosine Transform(DCT)?
I am trying to understand the difference between DCT type 1 to DCT type 4. Also, it seems that DCT-2 is the most used type of DCT for all signal processing and image compression algorithms. Can anyone explain the reason behind it? And also what are the specific purpose and mathematical difference between different types of DCT's? Which type of DCT can be most useful for removing boundary artifacts of a signal and why?

Hi, I downvoted this, because downvotes mean "doesn't show sufficient research effort". DCT types are easy to look up on wikipedia. You're very welcome to read  resonable amount of text and write something like "comparing DCT-I and DCT-II based on {name of text you've been reading}, I can't understand why DCT-I does this and that, while DCT-II does such and such. I thought that it's so and so!" But "please copy a text about this topic that places that are very easy to find on the internet already explain, to compare four different things in all possible aspects" isn't a valuable question.

also, you use unrelated tags.

also, this honestly feels a lot as if someone has assigned the writing of a short essay to you, with multiple questions that you need to answer, and it feels like instead of trying to answer these questions as good as you can yourself, you're just hoping that we do that. I don't know whether this is really the case, it just feels that way to me, because you show no research of your own!

This is a good place to start looking.
My understanding is that you get variations whether the number of points are odd or even and whether there is a half-sample offset or not.
MDCT is another variation.  I dunno for sure what's different.

MDCT is different in that it describes a lapped setup akin to a filterbank that is critically sampled while being lossless. The different flavours of DCTs are lossless block transforms.
